# Can the Dimensional Slide arcanist exploit be used to escape a grapple?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, grapple, teleportation

The [Dimensional Slide](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/classes/arcanist.html#dimensional-slide) arcanist exploit allows for an special kind of short range individual teleport. Being a Supernatural ability, I understand you do not need to roll for Concentration as a Spell-like would require.

I am more concerned about the restrictions to movement that [grapple](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#grappled) pose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No,

you cannot move while grappled.

> ...Grappled creatures **cannot move** and take a –4 penalty to Dexterity...

Dimensional Slide (Su):

> The arcanist can expend 1 point from her arcane reservoir to create a dimensional crack that she **can step through** to reach another location. This ability is used as **part of a move action or withdraw action**, allowing her to move up to 10 feet per arcanist level to any location she can see. This counts as 5 feet of movement...

Comment: ...But can you take a move *action* if you're grappled?

Comment: Note the emphases, the ability is used as part of a move or withdraw action, stepping through the crack created, which counts as 5' of movement. You cannot move while grappled.

Comment: At the same time, though - there are other things that go in the move action slot (potions, for example!)